Different Customs for HaRachaman after Counting Omer - לנו
The Sefardi (Edot Mizrach) version is:

הָרַחֲמָן הוּא יַחֲזִיר עֲבוֹדַת בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ לִמְקוֹמָהּ בִּמְהֵרָה בְיָמֵֽינוּ אָמֵן:

Another version that some Ashkenazim use is:

הָרַחֲמָן הוּא יַחֲזִיר לָנוּ עֲבוֹדַת בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ לִמְקוֹמָהּ בִּמְהֵרָה בְּיָמֵֽינוּ אָמֵן סֶֽלָה:

Why the difference? Especially the לנו
Is it to do with צורך גבוה

The Ashkenazi version (all rishonim and old siddurim) is actually יהי רצון מלפניך שיבנה בית המקדש וכו just like after davening. Only in very recent years has the sefardi version caught on for some reason

The Ashkenazi nusach according to Minhag Anglia - see the Authorised Daily Prayer Book (UK) - does not have לָנוּ , אָמֵן or סֶֽלָה. It reads - see the comment above of @DoubleAA יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ יְיָ ֱלֹהֵינוּ וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵינוּ שֶׁיִּבָּנֶה בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ בִּמְהֵרָה בְיָמֵינוּיְהִי רָצון מִלְּפָנֶיךָ ה' אֱלהֵינוּ וֵאלהֵי אֲבותֵינוּ. שֶׁיִּבָּנֶה בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ בִּמְהֵרָה בְיָמֵינוּ. וְתֵן חֶלְקֵנוּ בְּתורָתֶךָ: וְשָׁם נַעֲבָדְךָ בְּיִרְאָה כִּימֵי עולָם וּכְשָׁנִים קַדְמונִיות

I am only discussing the nusachot in the question

@DoubleAA, this is the version used by most Jekkes, myself included
